# how to convert timezones based on state?

Tags: date, java-11

I need to convert a ZonedDateTime date to user's local date based on the US state provided. For example if the ZonedDateTime has a value `2023-05-12T23:59:59.0000` in EST then I have to convert it `2023-05-12T22:59:59.0000` for WI(Wisconsin) state user. So I need this to work for all US states

For this I can do something like

```java
private static final Map<String, ZoneId> STATE_ABBREVIATIONS_TO_TIME_ZONES = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        STATE_ABBREVIATIONS_TO_TIME_ZONES.put("AK", ZoneId.of("America/Anchorage"));
        STATE_ABBREVIATIONS_TO_TIME_ZONES.put("AL", ZoneId.of("America/Birmingham"));

//..... left for brevity
}
```

and then I can do something like this

```java
 // Convert the ZonedDateTime to a local date using the given time zone
        return zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(STATE_ABBREVIATIONS_TO_TIME_ZONES.get("WI"))
.toLocalDate(); // to return the local date
```

But with this approach I have to keep all the state mappings in a hashmap, so looking to see if there is a better approach that I missed or some out of the box library to do so.

Edit: states with multiple timezones at a time, we consider the timezone with majority of people of that state live.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Looking at https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_time_zone there are even states which have multiple timezones. For instance Florida or Idaho

Comment: I have edited my post but the requirement is to consider the timezone with majority of people in that state falls.

Comment: I don't know your app, but if you have any possibility to obtain the user's actual timezone (ie for instance from the user's device), you should do so and save that information with the user. Otherwise I'm not aware of any library providing such a 1:1 mapping, because it inevitably would lead to errors